# How to perform a binary search of several occurrences?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to perform a binary search on an array, and I must find **all** the occurrences of a string. I've tried with `bsearch`, but I don't know how to do it.

```
/* data structures */

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *value;
} acronym;

struct {
    acronym *tab;
    size_t size;
} acronymArray;

/* code */

char buf[256];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
for (size_t i = 0; i < acronymArray.size; ++i) 
       if (!strcmp(buf, acronymArray.tab[i].name)) 
           printf("Found: %s\n", acronymArray.tab[i].value);

 /* How to translate it with a binary search ?
    Of course my array was sorted with qsort previously */
```

I've tried this, but it works only for one occurrence :

```
if ((k = bsearch(k, acronymArray.tab, acronymArray.size, sizeof *acronymArray.tab, compare)))
    printf("found : %s\n", k->value);
```

I thought about adding a boolean variable to my structure « acronym », but I'm not sure...
This is not homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be quite simple: you find *any* occurrence with binary search, and then look forward/backward from the found occurrence until you find something which is *not* equal to the found item (or until you find the sequence end). All the occurrences must be sequential in the sorted list.

Comment: And if you want to avoid the linear runtime of the part that looks forwards/backwards, then you'll need a different binary search routine in two versions - one to find the first match and another to find the last, akin to `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` in C++. Both can be done in logarithmic time.

Comment: @Steve: an alternative would be just using exponential search: jump in increasing steps.

Comment: @Steve: this approach may be actually slightly faster than using 2 binary searches.

Comment: @Vlad: agreed, that exponential search will tend to be faster in the (probably common) case where the number of matches is small. I'm not sure it's any simpler to code, though.

Comment: @Steve: you're right, such a code probably belongs to a good library rather than everyday developer implementation.